# How to highlight the entire event on Event Click in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to highlight an event on my calendar when user clicks. I already have some basic code, but it's not working as i expected. The way my code works now it's just highlighting for a week and not until the end of the event as it is shown in the calendar. Here's some of my code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var lang = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');
  if(lang == 'hy'){
    var language = hyLocale;
  }else if(lang == 'ru'){
    var language = ruLocale;
  }else{
    var language = 'en';
  }
  var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locales: [ ruLocale, hyLocale],
    locale: language,
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
    events: '/events/get',
    eventClick: function(info) {

      // This is where it resets the highlight when user clicks on another event
      $('.fc-event-container a').css('background-color', '#3788d8');


      // This is where i set the background color of the event when user clicks
      $(info.el).css('background-color', '#00da4a');
      $('#info-container').empty();

      var html = 'basic html for div';
      $('#info-container').append(html);
    }

  });
```

And here's what it looks like on the front end.

[image]

I want to highlight the entire event even on the next month.

Comment: I think you may have found a little bug. I can reproduce your issue here: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/rNNybeV . If you wish, you can use that CodePen as the basis for [bug report](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) . It appears that in this case (and others, e.g. in the timeGrid view) an event can sometimes be represented by more than one HTML element. And `info.el` in the callback only gives you access to the one which was actually clicked. IMHO ideally it should give you access to a collection of all the elements which represent that single event.

Comment: @ADyson i am aware of that. I am just looking for the solution, thank you

Comment: My point is, there isn't one. If you look at the rendered HTML, there is nothing you can use to identify which elements form part of the same event. It needs fixing within fullCalendar. Hence my suggestion to make a bug report.

Comment: @ADyson i was even thinking about getting the text of the span and then highlighting the other lines that have the same text. Pretty "not-so-professional" but hey what can i do

Comment: It's a bodge, and you might get away with it. But it will fall down if you ever have two events with the same title for some reason.

Comment: @ADyson yeah, you're right. Kinda sucks to be honest

Comment: Agreed. But...fullCalendar is open source. They do, I believe, encourage [contributions](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) from others. So if you can work out how to fix it yourself in the source code you could submit a patch. That might get it updated faster and released in new version soon. In the meantime you could run your own modified copy in your project until it's official.

Comment: @ADyson i'll see what i can do

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing something similar. So, I would like to share my idea for you. 
See if it works for you.
What I did is to assign an id to each event at my code, like, 
Id for Event 1 is: no1, for Event 2 is: no2 etc.
Than I used [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) to assign the id of event as a class name to the event, so it will assign that to each element where the event is stretched.
The code would be as follow:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
    info.el.className += " " + info.event.id + " ";
}
```

Than in eventClick, use that class to assign your css at run time, as follow:

```
eventClick: function (info) {
    $('.'+info.event.id).css("background-color", "#00da4a");
}
```

Note that it assigned css but to remove that css and to apply to other event element, I will leave that logic upto you :)

**UPDATE:**

When next or previous clicked, and event is stretching till next or previous month, you may need to use global event id variable to store selected event id. 
And on next and previous button click, you may use that selected event id to change color of that event.

For example:

```
var gEventId = 0;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
   // First Call the Calendar Render code here...
   $('.fc-next-button, .fc-prev-button').click(function(){
      if (gEventId > 0)
      {
         $('.'+ gEventId).css("background-color", "#00da4a");
      }
   });
});
```

The gEventId is saved in eventClick as follow:

```
eventClick: function (info) {
   gEventId = info.event.id;
   $('.'+ info.event.id).css("background-color", "#00da4a");
}
```

To roll back selected event id to 0, you may click that event again or provide some other mean to unselect the event. The logic is simple, you need to check if clicked event id is same as already selected event id (value stored in gEventId), than set gEventId to 0 and unselect the highlighted background else highlight the background color and set gEventId to event id.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't keep the color once you change the month

Comment: @Areg, I updated the answer for this logic. Please mark and accept the answer if the solution worked for you, Thank you :)

Comment: Strange. Like i can see that the background color is changed when you click on a month now, but for a microsecond. It resets afterward back to blue. Now everytime when i click on next month it flashes green then resets back to blue

Comment: @Areg, Can you please share latest code at the end of your main question. Write UPDATE, and below it write the updated full calendar code only.

Comment: @Areg, here is the codepen I tried, it seems to be working as expected: https://codepen.io/khurramishaque/pen/xxxPjyN

Comment: But still it doesnt work when you're fetching data through ajax. It only works when you manualy fill the events.